# Download videos from server to users machine as response in django

Tags: python, django, youtube-dl

I have lunched a small any video downloader with written in django and youtubedl. Whenever user tries to download video it gets downloaded inside server in a folder `/home/SERVER_USER_NAME/Downloads`.Now how do i tell browser to download that video to users local machine?I have written a method `serve_file()` but its not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import AnyVideoDownloadForm
import youtube_dl
import os
from django.contrib import messages
from mimetypes import MimeTypes
from urllib.request import pathname2url
from django.http import HttpResponse
URL_LIST = ''

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    global URL_LIST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnyVideoDownloadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            URL_LIST = form.cleaned_data['url']
            return redirect('anydownload')
    else:
        form = AnyVideoDownloadForm()
        return render(request, 'anyvideo/home.html', {'form': form})


def serve_file(): 
    file_path = '/home/SERVER_USER_NAME/Downloads/video.mp4'
    filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
    mime = MimeTypes()
    url = pathname2url(file_path)
    mimetype, encoding = mime.guess_type(url)
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type=mimetype)
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = \
        "attachment; filename=\"%s\"; filename*=utf-8''%s" % \
        (filename, filename)
    f.close()
    return response

def anydownload(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ydl_opts = {
            # 'logger': MyLogger(),
            'quiet': True,
            'skip_download': True,
            'match_filter': youtube_dl.utils.match_filter_func("!is_live"),
        }
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            meta = ydl.extract_info(URL_LIST, download=False)
            context = {
                'title': (f"{meta['title']}"),
                'uploader': (f"{meta['uploader']}"),
            }

            return render(request, 'anyvideo/anydownload.html', context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
            ydl_opts = {
                'format': 'best',
                'outtmpl': '~/Downloads/video.mp4',
                'noplaylist': True,
            }
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([URL_LIST])

            serve_file() #<-------called above method here

            messages.success(request, 'Video has been successfully downloaded !')
            return redirect('anyhome')
        return render(request, "anyvideo/anydownload.html")
```

Comment: you would use `return serve_file()` instead of `return redirect('anyhome')` .

Answer (score -1):

Your code is almost right, but you just need to change one thing. And please send me the full source code.
Try this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import AnyVideoDownloadForm
import youtube_dl
import os
from django.contrib import messages
from mimetypes import MimeTypes
from urllib.request import pathname2url
from django.http import HttpResponse
URL_LIST = ''

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    global URL_LIST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnyVideoDownloadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            URL_LIST = form.cleaned_data['url']
            return redirect('anydownload')
    else:
        form = AnyVideoDownloadForm()
        return render(request, 'anyvideo/home.html', {'form': form})


def serve_file(): 
    file_path = '/home/SERVER_USER_NAME/Downloads/video.mp4'
    filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
    mime = MimeTypes()
    url = pathname2url(file_path)
    mimetype, encoding = mime.guess_type(url)
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type=mimetype)
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = \
        "attachment; filename=\"%s\"; filename*=utf-8''%s" % \
        (filename, filename)
    f.close()
    return response

def anydownload(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ydl_opts = {
            # 'logger': MyLogger(),
            'quiet': True,
            'skip_download': True,
            'match_filter': youtube_dl.utils.match_filter_func("!is_live"),
        }
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            meta = ydl.extract_info(URL_LIST, download=False)
            context = {
                'title': (f"{meta['title']}"),
                'uploader': (f"{meta['uploader']}"),
            }

            return render(request, 'anyvideo/anydownload.html', context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
            ydl_opts = {
                'format': 'best',
                'outtmpl': '~/Downloads/video.mp4',
                'noplaylist': True,
            }
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([URL_LIST])

            serve_file() #<-------called above method here

            messages.success(request, 'Video has been successfully downloaded !')
            return serve_file()
        return render(request, "anyvideo/anydownload.html")
```

**And please send me the full source code.**

Comment: Please don't just give a code listing as an answer. Explain how it is different to the code in the original question and why that fixes the problem. Also, ideally, only list the change itself (in context).